# Touchpad stops working after a while, Ubuntu 14.10, Dell Latitude E7440

Tags: dell, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my Dell laptop, every time after log in for a while, the touchpad would stop working so I have to use my USB mouse, I've tried to run these commands after the touchpad stopped working:

```
# gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
# entxinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
```

Some debug information:

```
root@ubt:~# xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2      [master pointer  (3)]
⎜  ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4      [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜  ↳ GlidePoint Virtual Touchpad           id=14     [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜  ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse              id=11     [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3      [master keyboard (2)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5      [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button                          id=6      [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Video Bus                             id=7      [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button                          id=8      [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Sleep Button                          id=9      [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD           id=10     [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=12     [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                      id=13     [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Only a restart can solve this issue temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed mine by doing:

```
rm -rf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf
```

Then restart.

Found here:
http://cjf.io/2014/10/24/fixing-my-touchpad-in-ubuntu-14-10/

Answer (score 1):

If the Touchpad stops working after a few mins. you please just connect with you external mouse and check the mouse pointer is working or not.
The issue may be of driver problem, This is the one of a temporary solution to overcome from restarting your machine.