# Dell Latitude e6420 - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - mouse touchpad and keyboard freezes after a while

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, dell

I've installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS, removing windows 7, through bootable pen. Everything went well during installation. With ubuntu already running, after doing all the updates, most of the times, after a while my touchpad and keyboard freezes. First, I'm unable to click anywhere but can move mouse, no keyboard working. Then, mouse freezes completlty.

Tried the solution displayed at:
[Touchpad stops working after a while, Ubuntu 14.10, Dell Latitude E7440](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587343/touchpad-stops-working-after-a-while-ubuntu-14-10-dell-latitude-e7440)

```
rm -rf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf
```

And at:
[Proper touchpad thumb & palm detection with libinput](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649103/proper-touchpad-thumb-palm-detection-with-libinput/678122#678122)

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt-remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then added some configurations

```
sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf 

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
EndSection
```

Still, after this, it froze again. All I can do is force shutdown.

Anything else I can or should do?

Comment: Update: 
Re-Installed 16.04, this time didn't do any updates and after a while it froze again.

Answer (score 1):

It was the graphics driver - i installed nvidia and works like a champ now (same issue, same pc)

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

basically -

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

to get into shell that won't get hosed when things freeze up

then:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to thank and confirm this has helped me.

TLDR: I use Dell Latitude E6420 with Ubuntu 21.10, the package name used is
nvidia-driver-390.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

First I tried driver version 495 (package name: nvidia-driver-495), it rebooted and go to to safe graphics - 640x480 resolution.
Then did "grep -i nvidia /var/log/dmesg", it stated that Nvidia NVS 4200 is detected but support has been dropped on this version, the latest version supporting NVS 4200 is 390, pointing to https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/drivers/unix/.

Hope this helps anyone else if the package version changes.
It's been stable after installing this package, previously it locked up about 1 min after booting onto the graphical logon screen.

Answer (score 0):

---

1. sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 acpi_enforce_resources=lax"

2. sudo bash -c 'echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend'
3. sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b36e" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo enabled > /sys$env{DEVPATH}/../power/wakeup'"

4.cp /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/

5.sudo nano /etc/rc.local

sudo sh -c "echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo USB1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo USB2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo USB3 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/wakeup"

=============also, get a usb powered hub, put the mouse on that.

Comment: each sudo comment on its own line

Comment: also, might try the 'mate' desktop...  http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

Comment: thanks. I'm going to be honest, after several days of searching trough the web I found out how to solved, but after trying so many things, don't actually remember which one worked... dumb me, I know. Thanks anyway.

Btw, I still have an unrelated issue with the installation, if I suspend or close my laptop, when open it back, or wake it, it starts to get slower and slower... reboot solves it. So right now, I never suspend my laptop. When I want to close, need to turn it off and turn it on.